# What is the idea that a moral system is ethical if it can function when everyone in a community adheres to it?

Tags: ethics, society, metaethics, social-ethics

What is the ethical paradigm from the title called?

To restate the concept in the negative, a moral system would be considered unethical if, when universally adhered to by everyone in a community, the community collapses or cannot function due to a fundamental incompatibility between every entity's interests actions.

Comment: Sounds like Kant's [categorical imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_imperative):"*Act only according to that maxim whereby you can, at the same time, will that it should become a universal law.*" In modern ethics this is taken as a meta-ethical principle (principle for selecting ethical systems) of [moral universalizability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_universalizability). See also [What are some examples of categorical imperatives/universalizable maxims relevant to modern ethics?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/47559/9148)

Comment: Good book on this. 'Liars and Outliers: Enabling the Trust that Society Needs to Survive' by Bruce Schneier